# img.onload to hide modal after all images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am using JSON to get paths of images and then dynamically creating the URL which I want to load.

The index.html

```
<div id="divData"></div>
```

The data.json

```
{
"images":[
    {"path":"slide1.jpg"},
    {"path":"slide2.jpg"}

    ]
}
```

The main.js

```
$(function(){

var siteUrl='data.json'; //get the json file via ajax
   $.getJSON(siteUrl, function(json, textStatus) {

    var rootObj=json.images
    for(var i=0;i<rootObj.length;i++){

        var fullpath="http://placehold.it/350x150"
        addnewimage(fullpath);
    }
    });

});

function addnewimage(path){
    var img=new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                $("#divData").append(img);
                alert("done load");**// this alert show after every image** load
             };
        img.src=path;
}
});
```

I get the alert after every image load but I want it once when all the images have loaded.
How can I do that?

NOTE: I am looking for a event driven way. I know that it can be done by a counter keeping track of loaded images,etc. But that's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(window).load(function() { ... });` to ensure all the images and other contents are loaded fully.

If you want specific solution for only images here it is:

```
$(function() {  

      // To keep track of how many images have loaded
    var loaded = 0;

      // Let's retrieve how many images there are
    var numImages = 10;

      // Let's bind a function to the loading of EACH image
    $("img").load(function() {

          // One more image has loaded
        ++loaded;

          // Only if ALL the images have loaded
        if (loaded === numImages) {

              // This will be executed ONCE after all images are loaded.
            function() { ... }   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not an efficient approach. FYI, there is a direct jQuery method .done http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: thanks but, is there a event i can listen to, i dont want to track the count and the number of images etc..it does work fine but was looking for a event driven way

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var noOfImages = 0;
$(function () {
    var siteUrl = 'data.json'; //get the json file via ajax
    $.getJSON(siteUrl, function (json, textStatus) {

        var rootObj = json.images;
        noOfImages = rootObj.length; // No of images to be loaded

        for (var i = 0; i < rootObj.length; i++) {
            var fullpath = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
            addnewimage(fullpath);
        }
    });

});

function addnewimage(path) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        $("#divData").append(img);
        noOfImages -= 1;

        if (noOfImages === 0) {
            alert("All images are loaded"); 
        }
    };
    img.src = path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `.success()` method like this:

```
$(function(){

var siteUrl='data.json'; //get the json file via ajax
   $.getJSON(siteUrl, function(json, textStatus) {

    var rootObj=json.images
    for(var i=0;i<rootObj.length;i++){

        var fullpath="http://placehold.it/350x150"
        addnewimage(fullpath);
    }
    }).success(function() {
      alert("done"); //do like this 
    });

});
  function addnewimage(path){
      var img=new Image();
              img.onload = function(){
                  $("#divData").append(img);
               };
       img.src=path;
  }
});
```

Comment: this does not work as the img.onload is firing its own ajax events so the "done" shows up as soon as the getJSON is over

Comment: @krv it is working.. i have tried myself.. is there any error??.. your js code is missing `});` in the end ..

Comment: no no errors, the code is fine i checked it.. the thing is that the "done" shows up before the images.. also the networks tab in the developer tools show as i mentioned separate AJAX called to images.. so the the "done" is showed when the AJAX call of getJSON is complete but the AJAX calls for images is still in process

Comment: Give it a try using `.success()` instead of `.done()`  @krv. But .success is deprecated since jquery 1.8.

Comment: same thing happes as i said we are using the .done and .success on the $.getJSON so it is alerting before the images are loaded